# How can I get the authorization from the site using requests Python

Tags: python-3.x, ajax, scripting, python-requests

there is a site I want to send some requests to, but it asks me the authorization when sending a post-type request.

This is the form of authorization:

[image]

The problem is that it is inside the Request Headers, and when I do this process:

r = requests.get("https://www.examplesite.com")
print(r.headers)

The Response Headers data is returned, but I want to get the authorization from the request headers ..

how it would be ?

this response headers ..

[image]

and this request heades, I want to get it..

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the authorization is in the request header, you need to set it when you are forming the request, before you send it to the intended host.

```
import requests

headers = { "authorization": "random-gibberish-that-is-the-auth" }
request = requests.post("https://www.examplesite.com", headers=headers)
```

This means, you will need to have an authorization key that you can assign to the `authorization` header prior to making your request.

Comment: Could you clarify how it failed? Is the authorization key you attempted to pass valid?